How to enable parallel execution of ABAP in PyRFC?
I am migrating a project to PyRFC, using a server configuration.
My program is registering a function that has to be called. The incoming data is splitted across 3 DTP, hence my function will be called 3 times.
When we set the parallel execution in SAP to 1, everything is working fine and I am receiving one packet after another. But this is too slow! We need to have the executions running in parallel.
When we set the execution to 3 in SAP, it says that all packets are sent but I'm only receiving the first one.
Here is my implementation of PyRFC :

def launch_server():
    """Start server."""

    # create server for ABAP system ABC
    client_params = {
        "lang": config["lang"],
        "client": config["client"],
        "passwd": config["passwd"],
        "user": config["user"],
        "sysnr": config["sysnr"],
        "ashost": config["ashost"],
        "dest": config["dest"],
        "conncount": config["conncount"],
        "trace": config["trace_level"]
    }

    # Define server parameters (SAP RFC server setup)
    server_params = {
        "gwhost": config["gwhost"],
        "gwserv": config["gwserv"],
        "dest": config["dest"],
        "program_id": config["program_id"],
        "trace": config["trace_level"]
    }

    server = Server(
        server_params=server_params,
        client_params=client_params,
        config={
            "check_date": False,
            "check_time": False,
            "port": 8081,
            "debug": config["use_server_debug"] != 0,
            "server_log": config["use_server_debug"] != 0
        }
    )

    # expose python function to be called by ABAP
    server.add_function("MY_FUNCTION", myFunctionImplementation)

    # start server
    server.serve()

# Enable pyrfc logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

server_thread = Thread(target=launch_server)
server_thread.start()

In this example, when SAP is sending 3 packets at the same time I only receive one and myFunctionImplementation is called only once.
In this example, conncount is set to 10 which seems the only things to change to allow parallelization.
I hardly understand SAP internal processes, what am I missing? Is it possible to handle all three packets at the same time?
I also tried to enable bgRFC without success.

I managed to have the expected behaviour by running several instance of my code.
Beware, as PyRFC is not thread safe, you cannot just run several Thread inside the same python application or use multiprocessing to open various processes. Both of this method have resulted in crashes.
Instead, I had to create a good old fashioned bash script that run several times the python script in background.
(I also used wait and trap to have a clean exit)
My bash script is looking like this:
#!/bin/bash

# To clean subprocesses
trap "trap - SIGTERM && kill -- -$$" SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT

# Function to display usage instructions
usage() {
  echo "Usage: $0 --threads <number>"
  echo "  --threads: Specify the number of threads (must be a positive integer)"
  exit 1
}

# Default value for threads
THREADS=1

# Parse arguments
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ] && [ "$1" == "--threads" ]; then
  if [[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [ "$2" -gt 0 ]; then
    THREADS=$2
  else
    echo "Error: --threads must be a positive integer."
    usage
  fi
else
  echo "Error: Invalid arguments."
  usage
fi

echo "Will be starting $THREADS instances"
for i in $(seq 1 $THREADS);
do
  python3 myscript.py &
done

# Wait for children to finish
wait

